# Get audiences insights using Keras and TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Recently I've discovered [Keras](https://keras.io/) and [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and I'm trying to get into ML. I have manually classified train and test data from my users DB like so:

9 features and a label, the features are events in my system like "user added a profile picture" or "user paid X for a service" and the label is positive or negative R.O.I (1 or 0)

*Sample:*
[image]

I have used the following code to classify the users:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

train_data = np.loadtxt("train.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
test_data = np.loadtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)

X_train = train_data[:, 0:9]
Y_train = train_data[:, 9]

X_test = test_data[:, 0:9]
Y_test = test_data[:, 9]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=12000, batch_size=10)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print("\n\n\nResults: %s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

And got a 89% accuracy. That worked great in order to label a user as a valued customer.

**Q** : How can I extract the features that contributed for the possitive R.O.I so I can boost their focus in the UX?

**Or** : What is the approach to find the best combined segment of audiences?

Comment: Your model is deep (so it extracts complex and probably really hard to interpret features), you can use a 1 layer network and look at the weights or can use random forests or decision trees to find most prominent features. Other than that I think you can only try a lot of different test inputs and try to see any obvious correlations between the input and output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get your point ... how would use decision trees to find those features?

Comment: You can use sklearn to find important features using statistical measures or trees. [Check this post](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) for more information, or you check this [sample code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) using etree classification. Overall I had the best results using random forests, but as always it depends on application. And I'd recommend you to maybe built a model with the given important features and compare test accuracy results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go

Comment: There is no easy answer, but there is a fair amount of literature on the topic. [Here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4f46/2bdbd742554945050f0d163b0a35447d1b1b.pdf) is some paper with a few methods, but you can probably find many more. Still, you will at most get feature-wise insights, but not about interactions between features. As mentioned, there are more "white-box" methods like trees or Bayesian networks, if they fit your problem.

Comment: Such a deep net makes it almost impossible to understand features. You can give tree based methods a try as it was stated above. Usually the have some feature to extract and easily plot the tree and feature importance so you can understand how decisions are made. You can take some RandomForest example from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or play with XGBoost. One example can be found [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/) and a lot more on Kaggle.

Comment: When using a 1 layer network as @umutto suggested, you could additionally put a L1 regularizer on the weights, which enforces sparsity. Hence, weights of uninteresting features are (hopefully) pushed towards zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people said, there is no easy answer, and mine is not intended to be **the answer**, but I think you might try something like this.

**Take a look approach:**

- Predict the result for all your clients
- Filter the good clients and plot their features
- Filter the bad clients and plot their features
- Can you see an evident pattern? Ex: most failures don't have feature x.

**Create fake clients with combined features:**

- First, create fake customers that have only one feature, from 1 to 9. (Client 1 has only feature 1, client 2 has only feature 2 and so on)
- Predict the results for these clients
- Check if any of the features give nice results (this may not be the actual result yet, but keep note)

Above, you can see the result of each feature alone, but that is not very likely, is it?

- Now you can create all combinations of two features. There are 36 combinations (9 x 8 / 2) of those features. (F1/F2 ; F1/F3 ; F1/F4 ....)
- Predict and look at the good clients (keep note of the best combinations)

Keep going, combinations of 3 features (84 combinations)
Combinations of 4 features (126 combinations)

**Compare the results between each step above**:

- Take all failure clients with 4 features. Compare with the success clients with 1 feature: is the one success feature present in the failed clients? If not, you have very probably found an independent success feature.
- Any feature is missing in all failure candidates of all tests? This is another independent success feature.

Similar to the first one, you can compare 4 feature failures with 2 feature successes and see if any pair of features are successful.

And so on.

**Take the real clients and filter them considering the above results:**

- From the real clients, take all those that have the single feature you thought to be success. Confirm they're actually success
- Do the same with real clients that have the feature pairs you considered to be success. Confirm if they are.

You can do the same approach assuming certain features may lead to failure instead of leading to success. Or instead of looking at present features, look at missing features, etc.